# Is there a term for expander-like graphs that expand only large subsets?

Tags: expanders, bipartite-graphs

I would like to find a bipartite graph $G(L, R)$ with the following properties/constraints:

1. For every subset $S \subseteq R$ with $\bf{|S| \geq \alpha |R|}$, its neighborhood $\Gamma(S)$ satisfies $|\Gamma(S)| \geq \beta |L|$.
2. Maximum degree among all vertices in $L$ is as small as possible.

Note that this is not a typical expander graph. In particular the differences are that,

- the constraint on $|\Gamma(S)|$ in property 1. does not depend on $|S|$
- property 1. cares only about "large" sets, not small ones (unlike usual definition)

I have been able to show that such graphs exist for small enough degree using the usual probabilistic method. However I was wondering if graphs with such properties have already been studied and if there are references with better guarantees and a name for these graphs.

Comment: Why will a standard expander not satisfy the conditions you have? In particular one several disjoint expanders of equal size and that graph seems to satisfy your conditions.